# SQL - Return first instance of record when many instances are found in database

Tags: sql, coldfusion, greatest-n-per-group

I am working with some inherited code and having trouble solving the following issue: I would like to be able to search our inventory database by a number of criteria, including hardware serial number and comments left about the hardware. I then would like to return a list of pieces of hardware in our inventory that match this search criteria.

The issue I am having is that there may be multiple comments for one piece of hardware, so when returning the list of hardware, I see multiple results for the same piece (because of the joining to the Events table). How can I display the record once for each piece of hardware instead of multiple records for each piece of hardware?

Here is a snippet of the SQL query minus all of the if statements containing search parameters and such:

```
SELECT 
 UPPER(Hardware.HardwareSerialNumber) AS HardwareSerialNumber,
 UPPER(Hardware.HardwareName) AS HardwareName,
 Hardware.HardwareFirstDeploymentDate,
 Hardware.HardwareActive,
 Hardware.HardwareAccountNumber,
 Hardware.BillingAccountNumber,
 Hardware.LastUpdated,
 Hardware.Comments,
 Events.EventComments 
FROM 
 Hardware 
LEFT JOIN 
 Events 
ON
 Hardware.HardwareSerialNumber = Events.HardwareSerialNumber
WHERE 1=1
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Comment: Depends on which `EventComment` you want to show.  One option, remove the join and use a correlated subquery; another option, aggregation; another option, window functions with a subquery.  Just depends...

Comment: I did forget to mention, I would like to be able to search based on the EventComments column as well. I have tried a subquery inside the select and I am able to return one result for each piece of hardware, but I am not able to use search parameters within the subquery.

Comment: (Edit) Well, if there are four (4) EventComments related to one (1) piece of hardware, which one do you want to display and why - and how will "searching" impact that result? Also, different vendors have different syntax. What is your DBMS and version?

Comment: *but I am not able to use search parameters within the subquery* Can you please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33354769/edit) with what you tried and any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

I read your question and the comments a few times and I think your question is perhaps simpler than we are making it. It sounds like you have the data you WANT but just can't figure out how to tease out subsets from it. I would suggest that the following approaches are possible.

---

**GROUP**
This is a solution on the client side Since you have the data you want, order by serial number then output based on the GROUP param of cfoutput. Something like:

```
<cfoutput group="serialnumber">
.... output a line item for the hardware.
    <cfoutput group="comments">
            ... line item for each comment.
</cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

Of course if you just want to show the hardware piece itself, just do the OUTER cfoutput and skip the inner one.

---

**SELECT DISTINCT Q OF A Q**
Again this is a client side solution. Since you have the data you want run a separate query of a query and select distinct the rows that are related to the hardware (sans comments).

```
<cfquery name="hardware" dbtype="query">
SELECT DISTINCT hardwareserialnumber, hardwarename
FROM qryHardware
</cfquery>
```

...where qryHardware in the example is the name of the query returned above. Then use this subquery as you need.

---

**Split Queries**

You might try just running 2 queries, one containing the hardware and the other the comments. If you need to search against the comments use a subquery to figure out WHICH hardware serials you should be working with, then pull in the comments in a second query. Often people work really really hard to get all the data into one query - which is a laudible goal and lets the DB do what it does best, but there are times when it is a bit of a wasted effort. Lineheader / lineitem or Item / comment  can be one of those times IMO.

Comment: Mark makes some good points. One additional thought, comments do not have to be included in the SELECT list in order to be searched. If you simply want to display a distinct list of matching hardware, use a `WHERE EXISTS (...)` clause, rather than a JOIN.